# Extracting a string containing a `<br>` using BeautifulSoup returns `None`

Tags: python, string, beautifulsoup

I'm using BeautifulSoup, and I need to get the `xxx` string from the following line:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<p class="object-attr-value"> xxx <br/> yyy <br/></p>',
                      'html.parser')
```

Usually, I would do the following:

```
one_a_tag = soup.p
t = one_a_tag.string
t
```

But that doesn't work, it returns `None`. However, if I delete `<br/> yyy <br/>` the code starts working. How do I extract `xxx` from the initial line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `.strings`

```py
x_and_y = list(soup.p.strings)
print(x_and_y)
```

Output: `[' xxx ', ' yyy ']`

`.strings` is a generator so the `list()` call is needed, but you also can use a for loop

Comment: Thank you very much, got it!

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you get `None` as output when using `.string` is: (from the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string))

> If a tag contains *more than one* thing, then it’s not clear what `.string` should refer to, so `.string` is defined to be `None`

So, to get the text `xxx`, using your example, you can use `.find()` and pass `text=True` as an argument:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


soup = BeautifulSoup(
    '<p class="object-attr-value"> xxx <br/> yyy <br/></p>', 'html.parser'
)

one_a_tag = soup.p
print(one_a_tag.find(text=True).strip())
```